# How to set the default style in Bokeh?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bokeh

I'm writing a report whose plots are all rendered with `Matplotlib`. I've adjusted `Matplotlib`'s default to ensure that all plots have the same style.

However, I need to use `Bokeh` since it provides support for rendering legends for `Datashader` - a library being developed by the folks at `Bokeh`.

My issue is that the default `Bokeh` style is very different from my custom style. Rather than changing every single attribute in my `Bokeh` plot would it be possible to have `Bokeh` read from a style sheet in a similar way as `Matplotlib` does with `plt.use.style(['ggplot'])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.4` there are still open issues (features to develop as well as a few bugs, and more documentation support) around theming in Bokeh. What is currently supported is type-based theming using a `Theme` object that can be set on the current document.

The `Theme` object takes a JSON block, of the general form:

```
 { 
   'attrs: {
       'SomeTypeName': { 'foo_property': default_foo },
       'OtherTypeName': { 'bar_property': default_bar }
   }
 }
```

Or for a concrete example:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.themes import Theme

curdoc().theme = Theme(json={'attrs': {

    # apply defaults to Figure properties
    'Figure': {
        'toolbar_location': None,
        'outline_line_color': None,
        'min_border_right': 10,
    },

    # apply defaults to Axis properties
    'Axis': {
        'major_tick_in': None,
        'minor_tick_out': None,
        'minor_tick_in': None,
        'axis_line_color': '#CAC6B6',
        'major_tick_line_color': '#CAC6B6',
    },

     # apply defaults to Legend properties
    'Legend': {
        'background_fill_alpha': 0.8,
    }
}})
```

This JSON could also be read from a file using standard Python JSON tools.

If this also happens to be in the context of a (directory style) Bokeh server application, you can also provide the theme as a `theme.yaml` file in the same directory as your `main.py`. See, e.g., the [Gapminder example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/gapminder).

Comment: Thanks, @bigreddot this information was very helpful and I'll keep for future reference. `Bokeh` is a promising library. However, I found out that Bokeh wouldn't allow me to save the image as `png` programmatically, so, unfortunately, I had to give up on the otherwise great library `Datashader`. What I did instead was to adapt `eq_hist` to a `matplotlib` pipeline.

Comment: I don't understand. Datashader does not require Bokeh, and Datashader by itself can absolutely generate images. In fact, that's *all* it does: Datashader *only* produces images. The interactive integration with Bokeh just uses Bokeh to display the images in a browser, and report interactions (like panning and zooming) so that new images can be generated. Bokeh can't save images (yet) but you can use Datashader independently to save images. FWIW there is also an MPL+Datashader integration somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I didn't know about the `MPL+Datashader` integration. But what I really needed from `Datashader` was the ability to make legends. I couldn't find this functionality and my search led to [this](https://github.com/bokeh/datashader/blob/master/examples/legends.ipynb) which uses `Bokeh` to create discretized legends and that's why I started using `Bokeh`.

Comment: MPL support is only a prototype so far: https://github.com/bokeh/datashader/pull/200
As long as you let MPL do the colormapping, adding a colorbar is straightforward, if that's what you want out of a legend.