# Changing default font size in bokeh plots

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to change the default font size (for titles and axis labels) in Bokeh, to have a common style? Or do they need to be changed for each plot individually?

Comment: Check out this answer, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41987539/how-to-set-the-default-style-in-bokeh